# Should I place Launch Images and App Icons inside my Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode6.1

Can I just place my `Launch images` and `App icons` in the `Images.xcassets` without actually having to place them in my supporting files or any other files? Can I just drag from desktop to `Images.xcassets` so I can save on MB? Does Apple allow that when I submit app to the App store? Sorry this isn't a programming question but I have no idea and don't see `Apple guidelines` discussing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding resources to an `asset catalog` automatically includes them in your project. An asset catalog is basically a folder + some metadata. You do not need to include the images separately. It is worth remembering that 'Supporting Files' isn't an actual folder, but merely a group in the organizer; it's there so you can keep your sidebar a bit more organized.